# Cannot start docker container from scratch

Tags: docker

Nowadays I am trying to learn about the Docker but still have some ideas not clear;
I have tried to run an image that I just created, here is the directory;

hello (directory) :

- Dockerfile
- start.sh

And the Dockerfile :

```
FROM scratch
ADD start.sh /var/
CMD ["/var/start.sh"]
```

start.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world"
```

I have tagged as using :
    docker build -t mozer/hello .

Once I run the command;

```
docker run mozer/hello

no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container f22019aabc81f29fe17e849a2c040902ccadefe6cb8a8fe2612c83fe8eda40ea: [8] System error: no such file or directory
```

and once I run the command:

```
docker run mozer/hello /bin/sh -c
exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 3b54584092e70b639671aca66122a0b1f6b1e4327cb2471a8792c3b2337b0bcc: [8] System error: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
```

Can you please give me some ideas to find the solution ?

P.S. : I am working on a machine which is not connected to internet !

Answer (score 4):

`FROM scratch` is a completely empty filesystem. You have no installed libraries, and no shell (like /bin/sh) included in there. To use this as your base, you'd need a statically linked binary, or you'll need to install all of the normal tools that are included with a linux distribution.

The latter is what is prepackaged in the various busybox, debian, ubuntu, centos, etc images on the docker hub. The fast way to make your image work with a minimal base image is to change the from to `FROM busybox` and change your `/bin/bash` to `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Scratch image is an empty file system, there is not /bin/sh inside it.

Look at [Creating a simple base image using scratch](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/#creating-a-simple-base-image-using-scratch)

> You can use Docker’s reserved, minimal image, scratch, as a starting
>   point for building containers. Using the scratch “image” signals to
>   the build process that you want the next command in the Dockerfile to
>   be the first filesystem layer in your image.

You can add an executable compiled program and run it.